# cannot resolve constructor 'class_name(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to store data in database when clicking add button but an error appears when I created an object in MainActivity.java class with database class as shown [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTJt0.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure there actually is a constructor called `database` which has one `java.lang.String` parameter? On a side note, class names (and their constructors) start with a capital letter by convention.

Comment: Please copy and paste code here.

Comment: Also show your database class. You need to add a constructor which accepts a String argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. If you want to make this work, add a constructor something like this:

```
public class Database {
   public Database(String abc){
    //blah blah
   }
}
```

And follow naming conventions - Class names should start with capital letters. Constructors should do the same thing. And its not just humans who'll have a problem with this, IDEs will poke you about this as well. So the code you've written should look like this:

```
Database database = new Database(course.getText());
Database database1 = new Database("xyz");
```

For naming conventions, refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: it works thank you ,,,

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I suspect that value passed as course.getText().toString() is actually an empty string. Usually with Java objects the .getText() returns a String so there is no need for the toString().

Try rewriting that piece of code as:

```
database database1 = new database( course.getText() );
```

With a bit of luck that should work.

Comment: The same error generated!!!

Comment: `getText()` on an Android TextView or EditText does not return a string